# PowerShell - rename all files in local path\script directory and all subfolders

Tags: file, powershell, rename

so, trying to rename any file found in the current script directory and all subfolders. Doesn't want to work. This is what I have so far...what am I doing wrong? The issue I'm having is that it is not renaming files in the subfolders.

```
<# Renames all files in the working directory to have an extension of .hd #>

$files = Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Extension -match ".jpg|.jpeg|.png|.bmp|.gif|.3gp|.mp4|.webm|.mkv"}
ForEach ($file in $files) {
     $filenew = $file.Name + ".hd"
     Rename-Item $file $filenew
}
```

Comment: what's not working? what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing a `filesystem` object to path parameter of rename-item instead of a `string path`.

change this :

```
Rename-Item $file $filenew
```

to this:

```
Rename-Item -Path $file.fullname -NewName $filenew
```

#### You could also simplify your script to this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Include *.jpg,*.png,*.mp4 -Recurse | 
 Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name + '.hd' } -WhatIf
```

Note: remove `-whatif` to apply the rename action

Comment: Thanks @Kiran. The change of the rename-item did it. However, the simplified script didn't seem to do anything when I ran it (removed -whatif). Tried it with $Path and $PSScriptPath.

All good though, your first suggestion works for me. Thanks!

Comment: great!..ah yeah in the simplified solution i had copy pasted the `where-object` filter as a string which is why it didnt work .....`get-childitem -include *.jpg,*.png,*.mp4` etc

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, so $file.Name contains the extension so you need $file.Basename

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Extension -match ".jpg|.jpeg|.png|.bmp|.gif|.3gp|.mp4|.webm|.mkv"}
ForEach ($file in $files) {
     $filenew = $file.BaseName + ".hd"
     Rename-Item $file $filenew
}
```

Comment: Sorry @ManyRootsofAllEvil, the issue I'm having with my script (and yours) is that it's not checking subfolders.

C:\Test for example is the script location...it's renaming the file in C:\Test but not in C:\Test\Test2.

Comment: deary me, I completely misread your question, sorry about that